# How to Manage twitch API Errors in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, api, error-handling, http-error, twitch-api

I am using twitch api (twitch-python and python-twitch-client)to scrape twitch.

I am not sure how should I manage these httperrors as I am not using urllib.request.

```py
    game = []

    for a in lis[68:]:
        b = client.videos.get_by_id(a).game

        try:


            game.append(b)
        except Exception as e:
            print(type(e))
```

This error still arises even i use the except:
HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/videos/420146641

Comment: It might not be a class under `HTTPError`. Why don't you catch all exceptions first then print out the type of the exception?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Because the error message says it is HTTPError, and even when I try to catch all the error with ``` except error``` it still does not work

Comment: What you need to do is `except Exception as e` then inside the clause do `print(type(e))` to check the type. If it's not going into the clause then it's clearly not an `HTTPError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think I know where the issue lies. You're not wrapping the right code inside your `try` clause. It's unlikely that `.append` raises an error, so the error probably occurred while you were assigning `b` to the output of some error-throwing function. Move the first line of your code after the for-loop into the `try` block.

Comment: Yes it works now! thanks so much for your help!! :)